# optimalfill of a label

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I have two forms in my application, form1 sending a long string (more than 300 characters) or short string (less than 50 characthers) to a label on form2 with a click of a button, I'm using a label because I can't find a memo component with transparent background, and Canvas stuff requires a long code compared with the label properties.

```
Some label properties
Align == alClient
Alignment = taCenter
Layout = tlCenter
WordWrap = True
AutoSize = True
OptimalFill = True
```

The idea is to adjust the height of the text with OptimalFill, but when I send a long string to the label, the font size, goes all wrong, sometimes the label fills right (when I repeat a long string after a short string for example).

With a:

```
showMessage(IntToStr(label.Font.Size));
```

I've got some weird changes on the font size, if I send a string with 100 chars for the first time I got a font like 18, if I send a string with 20 I got a font like 30 and if I send the same string with 100 chars, I got a 22 (numbers are just an example, not the real / right ones), and not even what they should be btw

IF I change the Caption, the text height goes bad (still the font size of the first string that I've used), it only changes when I send a small string, things just go strange.

Following the above example will be something like:

```
string with 100 chars returns a font size of 20
string with 70  chars returns a font size of 20 //should be arround 25 or so
string with 10  chars returns a font size of 40
string with 100 chars returns a font size of 22
```

Already tried:

```
// to 'reset' the font size then put the string on the caption and later the real string
Caption: = '';
Caption: = # 0;
Caption: = ' ';
Caption: = '-'; 

Label.Update; // to update the 'math'    
Label.Refresh; // to update the 'math'    
Label.Repaint; //one by one and all togheter

Label.AdjustSize

Application.ProcessMessages

Form2.Update

Label.UpdateBaseBound

Labe.AdjustFontForOptimalFill;
```

I tried after and before the 'on click sent string to'

```
label.Caption: = stringGrid.Cells [0, stringGrid.Row];
```

Also tried enable and disable the label to 'reset' everything.

Nothing works right, things have a strange value (font size) and the font size depends on the length of the sequence.

How can I make it work right and create the right source calculation each time Legend changes?

Arch Linux X64 with the latest Lazarus (QT) using Gnome 3.22.3 (not sure if this is relevant)

Comment: Two ingredients for automatic adaption of layout in case of changing texts etc: (1) Activate the label's AutoSize and Wordwrap. Use AutoSize of other controls as well. (2) Learn to use the AnchorEditor of the Lazarus IDE to link controls to each other and / or to their container. This is a phantastic tool to make sure that every control gets the place it needs.

Comment: No lucky in this project, nothing seems to make it work right, someone describe it like a bug on lazarus page when I've tried the Lazarus forum, but you solved my problem with another application, where I can use it to make the register page elastic instead of a fixed width form, I'm a beginner in programming, so this anchor it's very useful. Thanks for your hint.